# asp.net How do diisplay the Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage error page

Tags: asp.net

I need to display the Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage webpage on iexplorer when there is an encounter error. How do I do that? I tried throwing an exception but that did not work.

Thanks

Comment: That error means it couldn't connect to your site.  Why on earth would you want to co-opt that to mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

- You could navigate to an non-existent site and get the error.
- Then use View Source and copy the HTML.
- Then create your own fake page.